# using 2 language switchers in the same node

Tags: i18n-l10n, 9

So i am not sure if this is doable or not, I am trying to add 2 language switchers block to the same node. I would like to have one language switcher for my content type that will be in charge of translating the content only. the other language switcher would be global in my navbar and will be in charge of translating the whole site.

would this idea be doable or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal supports having one language for the content (controlled by a language switcher block) and a separate language for the site UI.

You can set this up like this:

- Add a language switcher block for the content.
- Enable **Account administration pages** at `/admin/config/regional/language/detection`.  ([docs here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/multilingual-guide/setting-the-language-for-administration-pages))

Can you actually have two different language switcher blocks in the UI that do different things?  No, not without a lot of custom coding.

Comment: Thank you. I think i found a work-around. Using Paragraphs to create a component that will allow users to write translations within the same en page. then hide/show content based on buttons from the paragraph.